# Trying to get Dynamically created page to not 404

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, yoast

Hi I am having an issue of a page loading correctly but with the status code of 404. This is resulting in the page not indexing correctly.

The page is dynamically created which i believe is causing the issue, which is then picked up by yoast seo and declared a 404. I know I can add code in that will prevent this but the 404 status code still remains which will cause the page not to index.

I have tried searching and I can't find a simple solution to this can anyone help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add to your function file a hook like this :

```
add_action( 'wp', 'check_404' );
```

With a function like this one :

```
function check_404(){ if(is_page($your_page_id)){ header("Status: 200"); } }
```

You could change the is_page() if it's not a specific page and replace it with other WP functions. I've not tested it, but it might fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can say in more detail on the example of this page [404 link](https://antiquegallery.com.ua/product-category/antikvarnoe-xolodnoe-orugue-kiev/v-nalichii/page/9/)

if in the product category, there are fewer pages over time, for example, from 10 to 4 and then 6, as they are filled with new products

where the page number is the last two (Slash) and number/9/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32240820)